# Setting css values through html?

Tags: html, css, dynamic, slider, caption

I am using php, html, and css to create a caption that displays the title first then sliding even more to reveal excerpt on hover.

**Sample structure of basic post setup (simplified for clarity)**:

```
<div class="post-container">
    <a href="post-link.html"><img src="postThumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <span class="post-caption-container">
        title
        this is the excerpt
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS file**

```
.post-container{
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px; 
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.post-caption-container{
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px; 
    top: -45px; 
}

.post-container:hover .post-caption-container{
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out; 
}
```

**Inline HTML to override styling**

```
<div id="post-container" style="height: 140px;">
    <a href="post-link.html"><img src="postThumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <span class="post-caption-container" style="height: 50px; top: -25px; ">
        title
        this is the excerpt
    </span>
</div>
```

The portion where "style = top: -25px;" is causing problems.

My best guess is that the inline html styling "style= top: -25px;" is overriding values in both ".post-caption-container" and ".post-container:hover .post-caption-container", which is not what I want.

I need ".post-container:hover .post-caption-container" value to remain "top: 0px;".

I've spent about a week trying to resolve this issue, but I'm stuck! I don't know if this is impossible to achieve?

Any help would be appreciated. If this problem is impossible, perhaps an alternative method to achieve the same result, would love some different ideas as well! oi vey, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Positioning values like `top: XXpx` etc. don't work unless the element they are applied to also has a position set, such as `position: relative`, so perhaps try adding that in. I don't quite understand the example you are working with, but that might be all you need to get it working.

PS: Welcome to Stack Overflow. :-)

EDIT: In response to comments below, I now understand that the problem relates to an inline style overriding stylesheet declarations, and yes, inline styles carry more weight that stylesheet rules in the laws of the cascade.

However, there is one way to override the inline style, using `!important:`

```
.post-container:hover .post-caption-container{
    top: 0px !important;
}
```

So, you place !important after the rule but before the semicolon. (Note also the period `.` before `.post-caption-container` above. You left it out, but without it the declaration won't work anyway.

Comment: thanks! I tried it, but it doesn't work even if I declare position: relative. The problem essentially boils down to why declaring "top: xxpx" within the <html> tags will override all instances of that class's top:xxpx . There are two instances in the css file where top:xxpx appears, in the class itself and in the class:hover. I would need a way to set the top: xxpx distance through html without also setting it in it's class:hover portion.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've edited my answer above hopefully with some better information. :-)

Comment: Thanks! The . before .post-caption-container was a typo I made during this post. The !important fixed the issue OH WOW I can't believe that worked! Thank you so much!! Placing top: xxpx !important; within class:hover allowed me preserve it from the changes being made to class top: xxpx through inline styling.

Comment: Glad it helped, and I can't believe I didn't understand the question on the first reading. O well!

Comment: No it's okay, I think I was the one who was too confusing. I edited my original post so others who might have the same problem won't have trouble understanding/relating to my question. Hopefully it helps others too :D